# Как прописать условие для стилизации в php при выводе информаций из баз данных?

Tags: php, html, css, pdo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как написать правильно код ? ( Условие , чтобы каждый четный пост из вывода базы данных , имел отступ в 41 пиксель влево. ) Красным php код , желтым html

Comment: `.block:nth-child(2n) { margin-left: 41px; }`

Comment: Очень хочется бить по рукам за код скриншотами. Ну трудно, что-ли скопировать и вставить 27 строчек кода?